# RabbitMQ setting memory limit too low

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I get this message when launching RabbitMQ:

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 8-Feb-2014::10:43:42 ===
Only 2048MB of 23482MB memory usable due to limited address space.
Crashes due to memory exhaustion are possible - see
http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#address-space
```

When I follow that link, I read about how I should be using a 64-bit Erlang VM.  But:

```
ajax:~ maxvitek$ erl
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

...which certainly appears to be a 64-bit build.  This is with the `vm_memory_high_watermark` set to 1.  If I can get rid of the memory address problem so that RabbitMQ could use more of the system's memory, I will set that back to 0.4.  Any idea where to look to fix this?

Both Erlang and RabbitMQ are installed via Homebrew, running on Mavericks.

Comment: Did you found any solution?